# Update a Backbone Collection property on add/remove/reset

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a Backbone `Collection`, and I want it to respond in some way to its own updates (i.e. additions, removals, resets). I've run into this in various scenarios, but for the sake of discussion, let's say I'm computing a hash based on model ids, to quickly compare collections:

```
var HashedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    updateHash: function() {
        // set a simple hash based on model id
        this.hash = this.pluck('id').sort().join('|');
    } 
});
```

The question is, **what's the right way to keep my hash up to date?**

Possible options:

- Set a self-listener for events:

  ```
  this.on('add remove reset', this.updateHash, this);
  ```

  The problem with this is that some actions might be silent, but I still want to update the hash - this is particularly an issue for the first-time set, which can't happen in `initialize` because the collection doesn't have its models yet, and the initial reset event is silent ([relevant code](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-74)). Plus it means that any other component can mess up the collection state just by passing `{ silent: true }`.
- Set function overrides for `.add`, `.remove`, `.reset`, and/or `.set`:

  ```
  set: function() {
      Backbone.Collection.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
      this.updateHash();
  }
  // etc
  ```

  The biggest issue here is handling single `add`/`set` calls vs. multiple calls in `reset` - `reset` calls `add` many times, which calls `set` many times, so wrapping `set` means we'll update the hash once per item in a reset. If `updateHash` is more expensive than the simple example above, this can be a real problem. The other, lesser issue is that I end up with a lot of overridden functions, resulting in more semi-boilerplate code and more potential for bugs in core methods.

For the sake of discussion, please assume that a) computing the hash is expensive, and b) the hash is referenced frequently.

Is there any better approach here for keeping collection state up to date with its models?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: In my own code, I'm currently still using a self-listener with a fix for the initial `reset` event. But I should probably mark one of the below answers as correct, because I think they're both better than my current approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong on this but, I think your "biggest issue" (your words), is a non-issue.

`reset` calls `add` once.

```
// from backbone source - Backbone.Collection.reset
reset:
... code above ...
this.add(models, _.extend({silent: true}, options)); // note - silent:true
... code below ...
```

`add` calls `set` once.

```
// from backbone source - Backbone.Collection.add
add: function(models, options) {
  return this.set(models, _.defaults(options || {}, addOptions));
},
```

If you override `set` (as you have shown) `updateHash` will only be called once on a reset.

```
set:function() {
  Backbone.Collection.prototype.set.apply(this,arguments);
  this.updateHash();
},
```

Here is a fiddle for demonstration - http://jsfiddle.net/5ggCd/

You would also need to override `remove`

```
remove:function() {
  Backbone.Collection.prototype.remove.apply(this,arguments);
  this.updateHash();
},
```

Comment: That... is a very good point. That makes the method override option much more attractive.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide any specific info so it is hard to give a more detailed answer, but in general, you are doing things backwards. You shouldn't update the hash until you actually need it,

```
getHash : function(){
  return this.pluck('id').sort().join('|');
}
```

Instead of referring to `this.hash` you should call `this.getHash()` whenever you need it. Then all your syncronization problems go away.

If you want to do things when it changes then listen on the collections events, but nothing you said convinces me that there is a situation where a collection needs to listen to itself.

Comment: That's a good point, but let's assume that a) computing the hash is expensive, and b) the hash is referenced frequently - your hash-on-demand approach is much less efficient in this case then computing only on update.

Comment: Though it does occur to me that your approach might be correct, IFF the `.getHash` function compared the list of ids when the hash was computed to the current list of ids, and only performed the expensive part when necessary... that may well be the best option.